# Summarize wikipedia page with beautifulsoup4 and pyTorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, beautifulsoup, pytorch

I would like to use beautifulsoup4 to extract the text from a page on Wikipedia. Then, I would like to use torch to summarize it.

Here the code:

```
import torch
!pip install transformers
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelWithLMHead
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('t5-base')
model = AutoModelWithLMHead.from_pretrained('t5-base', return_dict=True)
```

To extract the text from URL:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winston_Churchill"
html = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")

# kill all script and style elements
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()    # rip it out

# get text
text = soup.get_text()

# break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
# break multi-headlines into a line each
chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
# drop blank lines
text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)
```

Then to summarize the text:

```
input = tokenizer.encode("summarize: " + text, return_tensors='pt', max_length=512, truncation=True)
outputs = model.generate(input,max_length=3000, min_length=200, length_penalty=5.,num_beams=2)
summary = tokenizer.decode(outputs[0])
print(summary)
```

Any suggestion on how to fix the root cause that causes the text to display as <extra_id_1> with dots? I guess that it is a problem linked to the formatting of the text from Wikipedia but I can't figure it out how to fix it.

Here the outcome:

> Blockquote
>  Winston Churchill (1874–1965) was a prime minister of the United Kingdom from 1951–1952. he was succeeded by neville chamberlain and antony Eden. he was also a minister of defence and a Chancellor of the Exchequer. he was succeeded by the Earl of Tunis and the Earl of london. he was also a prime minister of the uk from 1939–1929. he was also a politician and <extra_id_1> <extra_id_1> <extra_id_1> <extra_id_1> <extra_id_1> <extra_id_1> <extra_id_1> <extra_id_1> <extra_id_1>..........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: `text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)` from this line you are getting <extra_id_1> in your text??

Comment: @BhavyaParikh I tried it but I still have the same issue :(